# Sign in via the opened browser issue (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu-18.04

I have a sign in issue with my android studio running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS: The "Please sign in via the opened browser" dialog is popping up and staying still no actions of browser opening is observed. I have tried many times by changing my system's default browser and also by giving the custom path of the browser in the android studio web browser settings, still I could not figure out the way to do it.[image]